# Can I find the impressions of my YouTube channel using YouTube Analytics API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm using the YouTube Analytics API to report information on my YouTube channel. I can't seem to find a metric to find the total impressions my channel had (which can be found manually in YouTube Studio). Does YouTube offer it or is there a work around to find the data anyway?

Answer (score 0):

As always YouTube APIs doesn't provide access to a basic feature but here is a workaround:

Go on your [Channel analytics `Content` interface](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEl_ID/analytics/tab-content/period-default) in YouTube Studio.

Now select the time frame, pay attention to select one of following:

- [Last 7 days](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/analytics/tab-content/period-week)
- [Last 28 days](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/analytics/tab-content/period-4_weeks)
- [Last 90 days](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/analytics/tab-content/period-quarter)
- [Last 365 days](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/analytics/tab-content/period-year)
- [Since uploaded (lifetime)](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/CHANNEL_ID/analytics/tab-content/period-lifetime)

Because other options depending on the channel creation date are maybe unavailable.

Open the `Web Developer Tools` `Network` tab of your web-browser (by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> on Firefox for instance).

Reload the webpage using for instance <kbd>F5</kbd>.

You should see a request to `get_screen`, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking).

Pay attention to remove `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'` from it in order to get the JSON response in a human readable format. Otherwise you would face the following warning:

> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output " to save to a file.

Execute the cURL request and your channel `Impressions` value is in the JSON response at the key `/cards/3/funnelCardData/totalData/metricColumns/0/counts/values[0]`.

Note that I don't know for how long the cURL request will still work.